# Chrome Extension packing while developing - any better way?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do some chrome extension (web music play/stop) as a hobby project.
At the moment my process is like this:

1. Disable chrome store version
2. Make changes
3. Pack extension
4. Remove previous version of extension
5. Drag'n'drop new dev version

When I think I'm done, I upload the final zip to the dashboard, remove dev version and turn back on the chrome store version.

So this looks quite hard and not rational. Guess there is another way to do it.

Maybe I've just missed a good part of the manual, please point me to.

Comment: What I do is just load it unpacked, whenever I make code changes, I just hit `Reload` and it updates. It is definitely easier than packing it every time.

Comment: You even don't need to disable the chrome store version because the local / unpacked version will have a different extension id and can easily be run in parallel to the webstore version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @[devnull69](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030974/devnull69)

> You even don't need to disable the chrome store version because the
>   local / unpacked version will have a different extension id and can
>   easily be run in parallel to the webstore version

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked